# Delete A1 cell if B1 is empty

Tags: excel

I need excel formula for office 2007.
If cell `B1` is empty then make `A1` empty by deleting `A1` cell. I just want to make A1 empty not want to delete entire row.

If `B1` is not empty, Keep `A1` values unchanged.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you want if `A1` is not empty?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Insert in cell A1:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B1);"";"your value here")
```

It checks: If field B1 is blank, insert a string of nothing (`""`), else insert (`"your value here"`).

Comment: Thank you very much. I've missed one condition. if B1 is not empty, Keep A1 values unchanged. Plz give me a feedback.

Comment: You should add that in your `"your value here"`, as it is the result if B1 is not empty.. Say, if you have =B1+C1 in A1, it would be: `=IF(ISBLANK(B1);"";B1+C1)`

Answer (score 2):

You can't have formulas which delete cells.  Also, you can't have formulas which return "Empty".  However, you could do something like the following in cell A1

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B1),"","Not blank")
```

so A1 would be an empty string if B1 is empty.  But if B1 is also an empty string, then that formula would make A1 equal to "Not blank".

Alternatively, although it's impossible to have a cell formula which would make cell A1 blank if B1 is also blank, it is possible to do that in a VBA macro, such as the following

```
Sub TestCellB1()
    If VarType(Range("B1")) = vbEmpty Then
        Range("A1").ClearContents
    ElseIf VarType(Range("B1")) = vbString Then
        If Len(Range("B1")) = 0 Then
            Range("A1").ClearContents
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

That macro will clear A1 if B1 is either blank, or if B1 is an empty string.  To turn on access to macros, in the "Excel Options" dialog box under "Popular", you need to select "Show Developer tab in the Ribbon"

Comment: Thank you very much. I've missed one condition. if B1 is not empty, Keep A1 values unchanged. Plz give me a feedback

Comment: That's impossible in a cell formula.  You could do it in a VBA macro, but not in a cell formula.

Comment: excellent feedback. could you please give me a link for such macro??

Comment: I've updated my answer to show you how to do that in a VBA macro.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

This formula works for my work

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B1),"",C1)
```

I've Copied A colum to C. this is how it works.