# Mapping of two columns such as if one cell from column A get deleted value from column B automatically will be deleted

Tags: excel

I have one excel file and in **sheet1** in which I have two columns **Names** and **Salary**.

I created a different sheet as **sheet2** in the same file which has the **Names** column from sheet1 which has the formula `=UNIQUE(sheet1!A:A)` and one more column as **emails**.

It works fine when I am adding the new name in sheet1 it's reflected in sheet2 but when I am deleting the Name from sheet1 it gets deleted as well but emails are not deleted. There are just shifting below to the next value.

I want as soon as I delete the name from **sheet1** it also deletes the name and corresponding email from sheet 2 as well.

I have tried this formula but not working.
[Delete A1 cell if B1 is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16099221/delete-a1-cell-if-b1-is-empty)

Thanks

Comment: If the e-mail is not the result of a formula, you will need VBA to accomplish this

Comment: can you tell me what VBA script should I put? I don't have any idea about VBA.

Answer (score 0):

I think you use Microsoft365.
Also I think this is a job for PowerQuery.

Please find an
[Example-File](https://groeblacher-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/christian_groeblacher_de/EZEUCdg_-HBGqxSRg4VczyAB6k1mXyNWi4T7B6sJDubHsQ?e=k9dkfs) here.

1. Add the Name in Sheet 1
2. In Sheet 2 -> Right-Click > Refresh
3. Enter the EMail

If you now delete a Name in Sheet 1 (If there are duplicates, you have to delete it multiple) and refresh the table in Sheet 2, the EMail is also deleted.

[image]